# How the GeoNetwork TopicCategory selector for ISO19115-3 works

Tags: geonetwork, angularjs, choice-list

I'm trying to use the TopicCategory widget that GeoNetwork v4.4 uses in ISO19115-3 editor.  Looks like its implemented with an angular directive (TopicCategoryDirective.js), with an associated angular javascript module (TopicCategoryModule.js), and there's also a TopicCategoryService.js.  I'm new to angular and can't figure out how this control is invoked.  Is there some way to set up a field in config-editor.xml to duplicate the behavior with a different controlled vocabulary on a different field in the metadata?